# Bad request error in Apache2 when accessing http instead of https

Tags: ssl, apache2

I am a noob and I have recently started playing with my apache2 installation and trying to see how things are working. Also this exercise helps me figure out more things about apache2 than just reading some manual online.

But I am unable to figure out what I did now ?

So, here is my question: I enabled default-ssl (and have disabled default, i.e., have closed port 80, so that you can only connect the server with https)> I remember previously (say couple of days back) when i did the same and tried to access my website using http, it was giving me some error in the browser saying the web page could not be found or something. But today, doing the same thing give a nice error page saying one should use https instead of http.

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
Hint: https: // 127.0.1.1/
```

And, I actually like this. But, I am trying to remember what things I might have done in between to activate such nice error page which was previously not shown.

I know I did something and I cannot remember what I did and asking you to figure that out. I feel bit stupid out there. But, it would be great if any Apache Sherlock out there who could help me. BTW, I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

Thanks

Comment: have closed port 40, if you are talking about http then its port 80.

Comment: yes.. true.. that was a mistake.. edited my original question.. changed "closed port 40" to "closed port 80"

Comment: I get this problem, even after making a rewrite rule: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS